# My Ubuntu 18.04.5 PXE boot initrd isn't doing the kickstart file

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, pxe

I am setting up PXE server using Centos 7.9.  I tried to boot up the Ubuntu 18.04.5 server using the vmlinuz and initrd from "casper' directory in the Ubuntu 18.04.5 ISO.

In my PXE server boot configuration file (`/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default`) below, I use `preseed/file=192.168.1.5:/var/lib/tftpboot/ubuntu185t/preseed.cfg`

But the kickstart file would not start.  My ubuntu 18.04.5 just boot all the way to GUI.  Can anyone help to explain what's wrong with my settings?

```
LABEL    Ubuntu 18.04.5 Testing
KERNEL   ubuntu185t/vmlinuz
IPAPPEND 2
INITRD   ubuntu185t/initrd
APPEND   boot=casper netcfg/choose_interface=eno1 ip=dhcp netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.5:/var/ftp/pub/ubuntu185t/amd64 auto preseed/file=192.168.1.5:/var/lib/tftpboot/ubuntu185t/preseed.cfg toram
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the kernel and initrd files from [the Bionic netboot.tar.gz archive](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/).  I'm not sure the casper files are compatible with preseed.

The `pxelinux` config should look something like

```
LABEL bionic-install
        MENU DEFAULT
        MENU label Install Bionic
        KERNEL ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
        APPEND vga=788 initrd=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz auto=true priority=critical url=tftp://192.168.1.5/ubuntu185t/preseed.cfg netcfg/choose_interface=auto --
```